# Cocoa. How to show window in only tray application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, statusbar

I have created a status bar only application for the Mac OS X. Something like that http://d.pr/i/Covi . I created it by this tutorial http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/2010/01/creating-a-status-bar-application/ . Now I have a question: how I can show window by clicking "About" menu item? I trying that:

```
#import "IGAppDelegate.h"
#import "IGAboutWindowController.h"

@implementation IGAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    _statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [_statusItem setMenu:_menu];
    [_statusItem setTitle:@"LeoHelper"];
    [_statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Actions



- (IBAction)quit:(id)sender {
    [NSApp terminate:self];
}

- (IBAction)about:(id)sender {
    IGAboutWindowController *aboutController = [[IGAboutWindowController alloc] init];
    [aboutController showWindow:self];
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you using Automatic-Reference-Counting (ARC)?

Comment: @NSGod yeah, Im using ARC. I try your solution below and let you know my result!But I think that it will be work:) thank you so much! I still can't get used to ARC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess that you are using Automatic-Reference-Counting (ARC). If you are, then here's what's going to happen in the `about:` method:

You first create a local instance of `IGAboutWindowController`, then tell it to show its window. This will show the window on the screen, but, if your project is using ARC, the window will then immediately disappear. The reason for that is that as soon as the `about:` method ends, your local instance of the `IGAboutWindowController` will be automatically deallocated, and as a result, its window will be removed from the screen.

To successfully implement this `about:` method in an ARC-managed project, you should define the `aboutController` as an instance variable of your `IGAppDelegate` class like this:

```
@class IGAboutWindowController;

@interface IGAppDelegate : NSObject <...>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IGAboutWindowController *aboutController;

@end
```

Then implement your `about:` method like this:

```
- (IBAction)about:(id)sender {
    if (self.aboutController == nil)
       self.aboutController = [[IGAboutWindowController alloc] init];
    [aboutController showWindow:self];
}
```

Comment: Also, `-[NSWindowController init]` doesn't do anything useful. You'll need to either use `initWithWindowNibName:` or `initWithWindowNibName:owner:` instead, or override `init` in `IGAboutWindowController` to send yourself `initWithWindowNibName:` with the correct nib name.